# Other social media options not appearing in list

Tags: bug, status-norepro

Not much to say here, I just asked a question and noticed this:
[image]

However, these usually work on other questions on this network [except here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/99901/paypal-confirm-your-email-address-spam-emails-i-got-2-different-mails-within) so I am wondering what could be the reason for this.

Comment: you mean the extra commas in the image you supplied?

Comment: exactly, that's what I am talking about

Comment: Works here. Do you have a [3rd party ad blocker](https://adblockplus.org/features#socialmedia) or something similar that filters out social media links?